# libgdx: Why does my custom actor have a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, libgdx

I have created the following custom actor to draw lines on libgdx

```
public class LineWidget extends Actor implements Disposable {

private Position posA;
private Position posB;

public final Vector2 _A;
public final Vector2 _B;

private TextureRegion lineTexture;
private final TextureRegion lineTextureGreen = Assets.instance.Images.lineGreen;
private final TextureRegion lineTextureOrange = Assets.instance.Images.lineOrange;
private final TextureRegion lineTextureRed = Assets.instance.Images.lineRed;

public LineWidget(Position A, Position B) {
    this._A = A.getPositionVector();
    this._B = B.getPositionVector();
    this.posA = A;
    this.posB = B;
}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    setLineColor(posA, posB);

    float xdif = _B.x-_A.x;
    float ydif = _B.y-_A.x;
    float l2 = xdif*xdif+ydif*ydif;
    float invl = (float)(1/Math.sqrt(l2));
    //dif is vector with length linewidth from first to second vertex
    xdif*=invl*5;
    ydif*=invl*5;

    float floatBits = batch.getColor().toFloatBits();
    //draw quad with width of linewidth*2 through (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
    float[] verts = new float[]{_A.x+ydif, _A.y-xdif, floatBits, lineTexture.getU(), lineTexture.getV(),
            _A.x-ydif, _A.y+xdif, floatBits, lineTexture.getU2(), lineTexture.getV(),
            _B.x-ydif, _B.y+xdif, floatBits, lineTexture.getU2(), lineTexture.getV2(),
            _B.x+ydif, _B.y-xdif, floatBits, lineTexture.getU(), lineTexture.getV2()};
    batch.draw(lineTexture.getTexture(), verts, 0, 20);
}

@Override
public void setSize(float width, float height) {
    super.setSize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}

private void setLineColor(Position A, Position B) {
    if(A.get_value() != null && B.get_value() != null) {
        if(A.get_value() == 1 || B.get_value() == 1) {
            lineTexture = lineTextureGreen;
            return;
        }else {
            lineTexture = lineTextureRed;
        }
    } else {
        lineTexture = lineTextureRed;
    }
}
```

}

When I create the actor memory consumption keeps going up but I cannot detect where this leak is happening. How can I fix this actor to stop leaking memory?

**EDIT:** I am drawing this actor inside another actor which extends Group Actor class. Group actor class does not leak memory and the only thing it is doing for now is draw LineWidget by calling addActor(). This actor is then added to a stage inside a screen. I dont think this information is important but just adding it in case. I have tested all this actors and the memory leak begins when I draw LineWidget Actor.

Comment: new within render is always a warning sign. What happens when you remove float[] verts = new float[]?

Comment: @TomGrillGames I just tried to remove the new float[] but there is still a memory leak.

Comment: Are you only creating one actor, or might you accidentally be creating multiple ones? Is that the exact code for the actor? (constructor name doesn't seem to match the class)

Comment: @PeterR I am creating multiple actors (lines) inside a class that extends group. I fixed the constructor name, it was a typo

Comment: @Zack, OK. I was just curious if you had tried a small testbed to isolate to definitely just one actor with the code above, and confirm the memory was indeed increasing - or if there was another problem where perhaps you were creating actors when you didn't think you were and that was causing the memory increase.

Comment: Currently I am only testing this actor.

Comment: can we see this methods: A.get_value() and lineTexture.getTexture() ?

Comment: @TomGrillGames get_value() is a getter for the object Position, [getTexture()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#getTexture--) is the Texture method on libgdx class Texture. I have already tested without setLineColor(posA, posB) method but I still get a memory leak. Check the info I added.

Comment: Not much in your draw method. Kind of hacky, but did you try commenting out the line "batch.draw(lineTexture.getTexture()..." just to see what part of draw() might be causing it? (I know nothing will show up if you comment it out, but monitor memory). Otherwise, do you have your own code for batch.begin(), ... render and then calling batch.end() or are you using framework default for that?

Comment: @PeterR thank you for your suggestion. I ran the test and apparently the leak is happening above draw on float[] verts =. Now I need to find a better method because I cannot understand what happens there as I got it from an answer here.

Comment: Are you sure there's a leak? Maybe the GC hasn't cleaned up yet.

Comment: Tenfour04 has a valid point. If you think there are issues with your float[] verts you could maybe try libgdx's FloatArray. Create it once for your actor with the correct number of elements, not sure if there'd be any performance hit (compared to what you do) to call set(index, val) each time, then get your float[] by accessing the public items member. Shouldn't be any new creation each render step.

Comment: @Tenfour04 my app uses around 40mb, the GC doesnt clean up because it slowly increases upto 200mb. I will try Peter  's suggestion and see if it helps.